# Line numbering in two-column layout with ConTeXt

Tags: context, verbatim, context-mkiv, line-numbering

I am trying to spread code over two columns:

```
\definetyping[code][numbering=line,
                bodyfont=small]

\starttext
\setuplinenumbering[location=text,style=\ttx]
\startcolumns[n=2]
\startcode
this
is
some
code
spread
over
two
columns
\stopcode
\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

It renders like this:

```
1 this    2 spread
  is      3 over
  some    4 two
  code    5 columns
```

I tried splitting it manually with

```
\stopcode
\startcode[continue]
```

but that still renders the same thing. How do I fix the line numbering?

**Edit:**

Works with:

```
\definelinenumbering[code][start=100,location=text,style=\ttx]
...
\startcolumns[n=2]
  \startlinenumbering[code]
    \startcode
      ...
    \stopcode
  \stoplinenumbering
\stopcolumns
```

However, using it that way fails elsewhere in my document:

```
\startlinenumbering[code]
  \startcode
    foo
  \stopcode
\stoplinenumbering

sometext

\startlinenumbering[code,continue]
  \startcode
    bar
  \stopcode
\stoplinenumbering
```

This yields:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 31 in file /.../test.tex: ! Missing number, treated as zero                                                      

<to be read again>                                                                                        
s                                                                                                         
\page_lines_start_define ...ngparameter \c!start s                                                        
                                                  tep \linenumberingparamete...                           
\page_lines_start_followup ..._lines_start_define                                                         
                                                  \fi \attribute \linenumber...                           
\syst_helpers_double_empty_one_spaced ...1[{#2}][]                                                        

<to be read again>                                                                                        
\startcode                                                                                                
l.31   \startcode
```

Comment: Sounds similar to [this thread on the mailing-list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087207.html).  Especially note [Hans' answer](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087222.html).

Comment: It’s a bug because when you add text before the `typing` environment the numbers are also shown in the left column.